# Cassandra Table design for Historical state information

Tags: cassandra

My requirement is to design a table for historical state information (not exactly time-series). For ex: I have devices connecting and disconnecting to the management platform. I want to know the details such as (name, mac address, os, image, etc.) for all devices connected to the management platform in a given interval (start and end time).

Any help on table design for this use-case?

Comment: interval? what if device connects or disconnects in between? what should the results be?

Comment: That device should be part of results. When I say interval, I meant a time range between start and end. I want to know all devices connected in this time range. It should also include devices that are connected before start and ( disconnected after start or never disconnected till now).

Comment: yes.. i got your point.. but my question was.. what happens if device was connected at the start of the interval and disconnects before the interval ends.. should that be included as positive?..

Comment: So.. basically you want to track all those devices whose state is changed to 'CONNECTED' in the provided time interval.. independent of its disconnect time? Also (`"Device disconnects, only if it is down and administrator removes it/replaces it with a different device"` from your mail in mailing list) I understood that a device connects and disconnects only once.. and after disconnecting it is replaced by another device.. Is it the case? or a device can connect and disconnect any number of times?

Comment: Not exactly. Maybe a device is connected before a timestamp t1 and never disconnected. But when I query for all devices connected in range t1 to t1+1day, I want that device to be included. For your other question, a device can potentially connect and disconnect multiple times. This is a possibility,

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.. There are four cases to consider here (for example time interval t1 and t2) please let us know expected results in these cases:

1=> Device connected before t1 and was in connected state throughout (output=>connected).

2=> Device was connected between t1 and t2 and was in connected state throught (output=>connected)

3=> Device was connected before t1 and was disconnected between t1 and t2 (output=>???)

4=> Device was connected after t1 and disconnected before t2 (output=>???)

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by "output => connected". But in both cases 3 & 4, I want those devices to be returned in the response of the query. Basically the query is to figure out all active devices in that time range. I guess what we want to exclude is all devices disconnected before t1 and all devices connected after t2. I hope I did not miss any scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know if it connected during the interval, this should work in a traditional time series approach:

```
create table device_state(
deviceid,
timeofevent,
state,
details,
PRIMARY KEY (deviceid, timeofevent, state)

select details from device_state 
  where timeofevent > '2001-01-01 12:01:01.000' 
  and timeofevent < '2001-01-01 12:15:59.000' 
  and state = 'CONNECTED';
```

If you want to know if the device was connected the entire time, you will probably need to implement some client side logic.

Comment: Thanks Rachel for the response. But it will not solve the problem. Please look at my comments above to @karthick manchala.